# Как внедрить Preloader

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть скрипт генерации чисел.
Когда выбираешь большое количество комбинаций, процесс генерации затягивается, что-бы обозначить процесс генерации появилась необходимость в `Preloader`.
Как его интегрировать в скрипт?
Можно средствами `.gif` анимации.
Можно `CSS`.

```js
var tableEl;
 
function generate()
{    
    var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable"),
        numbers = (new Array(25)).fill(1).map((a, i) => a + i),
        result = [],
        qnt = parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity').value, 10);

    myTable.innerHTML = '';
    tableEl = document.createElement("TABLE");
    myTable.appendChild(tableEl);

    while(result.length < qnt)
    {
        var left = shuffle(numbers).slice(0, 5).join('-'),
            right = shuffle(numbers).slice(0, 5).join('-');

        //чтобы не были равны между собой
        if(left == right)
            continue;

        result.push([left, right]);
        fillTableWithContent(left, right);
    }
}

function shuffle(arr)
{
    return arr.map(el => {
        return {
            item: el,
            sort: Math.random()
        }
    }).sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort).map(el => el.item);
}

function fillTableWithContent(left, right)
{
    var tr = tableEl.insertRow(tableEl.rows.length);
    tr.insertCell(0).appendChild(document.createTextNode(left));
    tr.insertCell(1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(right));
}
```

```css
tr > td:first-child { color:red; } tr > td:last-child { color:green; }
```

```html
<input id="quantity" type="text" placeholder="Кол-во комбинаций" style="background: #ffffff!important;color: #8f2d00!important;font-size: 20px!important;"/>
<input class="annoying-btn" type="button" value="Получить комбинации" onclick="generate()" />

<div id="myTable"></div>
```

Comment: Такс, я так понимаю прелоудер вы еще никак не пытались внедрить? Сначала попытайтесь и напишите в чём возникла проблема

Comment: есть небольшая проблема - ваш скрипт блокирует поток, поэтому и анимация/гиф/все что угодно будет тормозить ( так как поток один в браузере, по умолчанию )

Comment: @ThisMan Плохо, спасибо

Comment: все что можно это показать статичную записать 'генерация', либо сделать ваш скрипт асинхронным

Comment: @ThisMan Мне бы хоть как-то обозначить

Comment: лучшим вариантом было бы сделать generate асинхронной, где за раз будет генерироваться только одна пара, тогда проблем не будет с добавлением анимации

Comment: @ThisMan Спасибо, я Вас услышал, визуально я представляю, но реализовать сам не смогу.(

Answer (score 0):

Познакомьтесь с асинхронностью JS. В этом случае вам нужна обобщённая функция, принимающая функцию generate и коллбек, который выполнится, когда закончится выполнение generate. До выполнения коллбека можете вставлять анимацию простыми манипуляциями с DOM. В коллбеке соответственно надо анимацию убрать и вставить результаты работы функции. Стоит помнить, что когда запускается длительный цикл, дальнейший код выполняется без остановки, поэтому установить прелоадер не сложно. Однако стоит обратить внимание на то что если ваш цикл выполняется долго - скорее всего ваш алгоритм работает не оптимально. Я не вижу в нем объем вычислений чтобы прелоадер вообще успел показаться.

P.S. Опровергая комментарии выше - природа JS асинхронна, потому блокировка интерфейса из-за этого цикла практически невозможна.
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F

Ниже пример реализации асинхронной функции

```
async function exec(loop, callback) {
    const res = await loop()
    if (res) {
        callback(res)
    } else {
        callback(null, "Error")
    }
}

function asyncLoop() {
    console.log("Set preloader")
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10000000; i++) {
        if (i === 10000000-1) {
            return i + " = result execution" // возрат результата
        }
    }    
}

exec(asyncLoop, function(res, err){
    console.log("Unset preloader")
    if (err) {
        console.log(err) // что в случае ошибки
    } else {
        console.log(res) // заполнение таблицы значениями
    }
})
```

Comment: хе хе хе, да только вот цикл не тот) В статье говориться о цикле _событий_, а у нас цикл обычный. Одно устройство движка, другое конструкция языка - разные вещи. Запустите генерацию массива на пару миллионов элементов, и попробуете в это время что-то сделать, даже кнопочки понажимать, сможете пронаблюдать результат

Comment: _Я не вижу в нем объем вычислений чтобы прелоадер вообще успел показаться_ изменение DOMa, например?

Comment: @ThisMan выполните в консоли браузера
(new Array(2000000)).fill(1).map(function(a, i) {return a + i})
лично я ничего похожего на блокировку не заметил.